# Nest foreach cycle and adding items to collection into linq methods

Tags: c#, list, linq, foreach

I have the following classes:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of persons:

```
IList<Person> persons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person() { Name = "Bill" },
    new Person() { Name = "Bob" },
    new Person() { Name = "Henry" },
};
```

And I adding items to new collection in `foreach` loop:

```
IList<Student> students = new List<Student>();
//Is it possible to nest the following rows in linq method?
foreach (var person in persons)
{
   students.Add(new Student() { Name = person.Name });
}
```

Is it possible to nest `foreach` and adding items into `linq` method?

Comment: @downvoter what is a reason to downvote? It is really interesting. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Similar questions are often asked. LINQ is not intended for processing data but querying/transforming data. `Add` is a `void` function which means no results would be passed through to the next operation/result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean replacing the `foreach` loop with a LINQ query (not quite sure why you are talking about nesting loops in your question) then you could try this:

```
IList<Student> students = persons.Select(p => new Student { Name = p.Name }).ToList();
```

or if you prefer:

```
IList<Student> students = (from p in persons select new Student { Name = p.Name }).ToList();
```

Comment: You can do like this too: persons.ToList().ForEach(item => students.Add(new Student() { Name = item.Name }));

Comment: @RafaelMansurHaddad That's just strictly worse.  Why would you ever do that instead?